# How can I fix multiple divs from overlapping in the nav bar?

Tags: html, css

I've made a website with html and the upper div is always like this no matter how long I make this:
[image]

Can somebody tell me how to fix that? I just started with that so I'm sorry if I might be a little bit dumb. Here is my CSS code for the div.

```html
<div style="background-color: black; height: 15px; margin: 0px ;margin-top: -10px; width: 100%;"></div>
```

Hope this is enough to let you know what's the problem. Thank you.

Comment: Please, don't share images of code. Provide it as a minimal example in a snippet, so the community can help you. :)

Comment: Jan, if you have a moment to provide us with more code then we could better help you solve your issue.

Comment: Either share a sandbox like **codepen** or insert the code in a block here.

Answer (score 0):

Width: 100%, is highly affected by margin and padding of its parent (body in your case). So, reset them first like below

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div style="background-color:black;height:15px;top:0px;margin-top:-10px;width:100%;">
</div>
```

Hope that's helpful and that's what I understood from your description that width is never 100%.